# iOS Charts: will intermediately not show the x and y axis values

Tags: ios-charts

I have a LineChartView embedded inside a UIView. I then have that "container" UIView added as a subview on a scroll view. about 75% of the time i have no issues the chart shows up fine. But seemingly randomly the chart will display with all the data points but missing the x-axis and y-axis values and the LineChartDataSet.label will be empty. The graph always works when i run it from xcode but then i will open the xcode build a day later and the x and y axis values are missing though i see the graph itself.

Here is what i'm seeing.

Bad
[image]

Good!
[image]

Here is my code

Creation of chart and container view

```
private lazy var elevationChartContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        return view
    }()

    private lazy var elevationChart: LineChartView = {
        let chart = LineChartView()
        chart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        chart.rightAxis.enabled = false
        chart.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        chart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        return chart
    }()
```

Configuration of chart

```
private func configureElevationGraphData(activity: Activity) {
        let locations = activity.points
        var distanceTravelled: Measurement<UnitLength> = .init(value: 0, unit: .meters)
        var graphPoints = [ChartDataEntry]()
        var priorPoint = locations.first
        for location in locations {
            let convertedDistance = AppConstants.shared.userSelectedUnits == .Imperial ? distanceTravelled.converted(to: .miles).value : distanceTravelled.converted(to: .kilometers).value
            let convertedAltitude = AppConstants.shared.userSelectedUnits == .Imperial ? location.altitude * 3.281 : location.altitude
            let newPoint = ChartDataEntry(x: convertedDistance, y: convertedAltitude)
            graphPoints.append(newPoint)
            let distanceFromLastPoint = priorPoint?.asCLLocation.distance(from: location.asCLLocation) ?? 0
            distanceTravelled = distanceTravelled + Measurement(value: distanceFromLastPoint, unit: .meters)
            priorPoint = location
        }
        if AppConstants.shared.userSelectedUnits == .Imperial {
            if distanceTravelled.converted(to: .miles).value < 1 {
                elevationChart.xAxis.granularity = 0.5
            } else {
                elevationChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
            }
        } else {
            if distanceTravelled.converted(to: .kilometers).value < 1 {
                elevationChart.xAxis.granularity = 0.5
            } else {
                elevationChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
            }
        }
        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: graphPoints)
        lineChartDataSet.mode = .cubicBezier
        lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        lineChartDataSet.lineWidth = 3.0
        lineChartDataSet.setColor(AppConstants.purple900)
        lineChartDataSet.fill = ColorFill(color: AppConstants.purple200)
        lineChartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
        let text = AppConstants.shared.userSelectedUnits == .Imperial ? "feet/mi" : "m/km"
        lineChartDataSet.label = text
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
        elevationChart.data = lineChartData
    }
```

setting constraints on chart

```
private func setupElevationChartConstraints() {
        elevationChartContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: elevationHeaderView.bottomAnchor, constant: gapBetweenScrollViewElements).isActive = true
        elevationChartContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapAndTimeView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        elevationChartContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        elevationChartContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.4).isActive = true

        elevationChart.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: elevationChartContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        elevationChart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: elevationChartContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        elevationChart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: elevationChartContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        elevationChart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: elevationChartContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

I've tried to restart he app several times this doesn't work.  the problem is completely intermitent it comes and goes and i never see it when i run it from xcode so i can't put in break points.